# Initializing Service Fabric Actors using DataPackages

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I am building a proof of concept application using Azure Service Fabric and would like to initialize a few 'demo' user actors in my cluster when it starts up. I've found a few brief articles that talk about loading data from a **DataPackage**, which shows how to load the data itself, but nothing about how to create actors from this data.

Can this be done with DataPackages or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Data packages are just opaque directories with whatever files you want in there for each deployment.  It doesn't load or process the data itself, you have to do all the heavy lifting as only your code knows what the data means.  For example, if you had a data package named "SvcData", it would deploy the files in that package during deployment.  If you had a file StaticDataMaster.json in that directory, you'd be able to access it when you service ran (either in your actor, or somewhere else).  For example:

```
// get the data package
var DataPkg = ServiceInitializationParameters.CodePackageActivationContext.
    GetDataPackageObject("SvcData");

// fabric doesn't load data it is just manages for you. data is opaque to Fabric
var customDataFilePath = DataPkg.Path + @"\StaticDataMaster.json";   

// TODO: read customDatafilePath, etc.
```

Comment: right, I get that it's just a file in a directory that I can load (as your sample above shows). The question is more about how to create the Actors from this demo data when the SF package is deployed into the cluster. Is there a point in that process that I can tie into that would allow me to create and initialize the demo actors? Can this be done inside the Actor constructor, the OnActivateAsync method (but this only fires when an actor is activated; is that too late?)

Comment: You would have to have a service that looked at the data in the data package and created the actors by calling them with ActorProxy. There's no built in mechanism to auto-create individual actors.

Comment: @kyko An actor has an interface/contract.  You could add a method to inject the data.  optionally, you could use the state manager directly.  At some point you need to request the actor to do something.  It's at that point that the actor is created.  So, in that respect getting data in via the constructor is probably not going to work.  Nothing stopping you for passing the data in through a method on the actor either.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I think what I will need to do is load the data package and store it in a private variable. Then, in the OnActivateAsync method is invoked, check the actor state to see if it has been initialized. If it hasn't then check the 'demo' data to see if the ActorID is there and initialize the actor from that data and save the state. Seems like I could take the same approach later on to load the data from a remote store, such as DocumentDB, instead of using a data package. Does this seem like a 'proper' approach?

Comment: You don't know where your actor will run (one of the reasons to use them) but if you replace "private variable" with "state manager", I think you'll get what you want